# Comparing date fields to "Today" using SharePoint search SQL?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, search

I am converting some of the queries I have from CAML to SharePoint search SQL and ran across an issue when trying to compare my Date metadata fields to "Today."

Specifically, I have the following part of a CAML query that uses :

```
<Leq><FieldRef Name="Article_x0020_Publish_x0020_Date"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Today /></Value></Leq>
```

When attempting to convert that into SharePoint search SQL I was following the [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443580.aspx); specifically the [DATEADD documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477432.aspx). I came up with this:

```
SELECT Title, ArticlePublishDate FROM SCOPE() WHERE "SCOPE" = 'Articles' AND ArticlePublishDate <=DATEADD (DAY, 0, GETGMTDATE())
```

However, when I use this query I get the following exception message:

> Name cannot begin with the '='
>   character, hexadecimal value 0x3D.
>   Line 1, position 296.

As an added twist, if you change the '<=' operator to a '>=' operator then it accepts the query:

```
SELECT Title, ArticlePublishDate FROM SCOPE() WHERE "SCOPE" = 'Articles' AND ArticlePublishDate >=DATEADD (DAY, 0, GETGMTDATE())
```

**Is this a case of the Monday's? Is Microsoft messing with me? Or is this really broken...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being treated as xml I suspect:

**<**=DATEADD (DAY, 0, GETGMTDATE()).

The rules of [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) mean that xml is higher than all datetime values, so this may be why.

However, I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with either Sharepoint or CAML, so can't offer a fix.

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of that... but you are right! If I use the encoded value (&gt; or &lt; instead of > or <) then it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Would removing the space between DATEADD and the '(' help? - the SQL parser may be treating it differently without the ( wedged up against it.

Comment: Chris thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to care about spaces. I get the same weird error no matter how much white space is there.